# Unity Repeat UV Coordinates On Quadtree Shaderforge

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, coordinates, shader, quadtree

As u can see in the image, on larger tiles (n > 1) the texture should be repeated as long as the current rect size.. i don't know how i can achieve this!

FYI, im getting the tile texture id with the alpha value of the vertex color.

[image]

Here the shader im using..

[image]

[UPDATE]

Thanks for clarifying the uv coordinates, unfortunately that doesn't answer my question. Take a look at the following pixture...

[image]

Comment: What are the UVs like on those larger tris? If the UV range goes past `[0,1]` you might see an effect like this (it would potentially grab pixels from the atlas that aren't part of the requested tile).

Comment: So for all rectangles the uv coordinates are as following [0, 0] / [0, rect.height] / [rect.width, 0] / [rect.width, rect.height]. So the uvs are going beyond 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shader is fine; it's actually the vertex UVs that are the problem:

> So for all rectangles the uv coordinates are as following [0, 0] / [0, rect.height] / [rect.width, 0] / [rect.width, rect.height]. So the uvs are going beyond 1

Your shader is designed to support the standard UV space, in which case you should replace `rect.width` and `rect.height` with `1`.

By using UV coords greater than one, you're effectively asking for texels outside of the specified texture. When used with a texture atlas, that means you're asking for texels outside of the specified tile -- in this case, those happen to be white, and that's what you're seeing in the rendered output.

---

### Tiling with an atlas texture

Updating because I missed an important detail: you want a tiling material.

Usually, UVs interpolate linearly:

[image: linear UV plot]

For tiling, you essentially want more of a "sawtooth" output:

[image: sawtooth UV plot]

For a non-atlas texture, you can adjust material scale/wrap settings and call it done. For an atlas texture, it's possible but you'll end up with a shader and/or geometry that aren't quite standard.

The "most standard" solution would be if your larger quads are on a separate mesh from the smaller ones:

- Add a `float` material param named `uv_scale` or some such
- Add a `Multiply` node that scales incoming UVs by `uv_scale`
- Pass output from that into a `Frac` node
- Pass output from that into the `UV Tile` node

Pseudocode is roughly: `uv = frac(uv * uv_scale)`

If you need all of your quads to be in the same mesh, you end up needing non-standard geometry:

- Change your UVs again (going back to `rect.width` and `rect.height`)
- Add a `Frac` node before the `UV Tile` node

This is a simpler shader change, but has the downside that your geometry will no longer be cleanly supported in other shaders.

Comment: I have updated the uv coordinates between 0 and 1 but for the larger rectangles i need to repeate the texture over and over till the rect size is reached.

Comment: @Michael Apologies, I missed that detail. Answer is updated with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks rutter!

i've implemented your solution into my shader and now it works perfectly!
so for everyone looking for this here is the shader im using now

Cheers, M

[image]